# Correct nvidia+intel graphics setup in 14.04

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Just upgraded to 14.04 to try to fix some other issues. Now, something has gone wrong with my graphics.

I have a Thinkpad T530 with Intel and Nvidia graphics cards.

```
$ inxi -SGx
System:    Host: xyz Kernel: 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.2) Desktop: N/A Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF108M [NVS 5400M] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
           X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: fbdev,vesa,intel,nouveau (unloaded: nvidia) Resolution: 1920x1080@0.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: N/A GLX Version: N/A Direct Rendering: N/A

$ glxinfo
name of display: :0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

I'm not sure what I did but now something is wrong with my graphics, as should be visible from the above commands. nvidia-detector says "none" as well.

I used to have bumblebee but then some website said to remove it and now something's clearly wrong. What's the right way to set things up? Should I try to add bumblebee back?

Here's what's installed now:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia
nvidia-319                  install
nvidia-331                  install
nvidia-libopencl1-331               install
nvidia-opencl-icd-331               install
nvidia-prime                    install
nvidia-settings                 install
nvidia-settings-319             install
```

Answer (score 5):

Before you proceed with the following please consider removing other nvidia drivers that might conflict.

For the latest proprietary Nvidia driver the following commands may be issued :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

For Nvidia Optimus technology (Nvidia+Intel) and the benefit of Bumblebee features the following must be issued :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

A final tip is to remember using optirun command in prefix of the 3D software command

```
optirun somegame-or-command
```

You can also test 3D with the following commands

```
glxspheres 
optirun glxspheres
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot.

Comment: When I try an optirun command: $ sudo optirun firefox
[sudo] password for xyz: 
[  526.850214] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].

[  526.850286] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.

Comment: But this might have fixed some other issues I was having.

Comment: Did you purge the older nvidia packages ?
"sudo apt-get purge packages"
instead of
"sudo apt-get remove packages"
to remove configuration files?
I think you can still reconfigure nvidia anyway with the following command
"sudo nvidia-xconfig"
See if this fixes your problem.
You can also test 3D with the following
"glxspheres"
and
"optirun glxspheres"

Comment: I don't have nvidia-xconfig, unfortunately. Do you know what package provides that?

Answer (score 0):

You can install all video drivers with the package `xserver-xorg-video-all`.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

Comment: There was a build error in one of the kernel modules: ` CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjNativeMapUser’:
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.2.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1539:26: error: ‘struct mm_struct’ has no member named ‘numa_next_reset’
                 pTask->mm->numa_next_reset = jiffies + 0x7fffffffffffffffUL;
                          ^
...`

Comment: Which caused: `Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-27-generic (x86_64)`

Comment: Also, `glxinfo` reports the same thing.

Comment: Did you copy the full line?

Comment: Yeah. I installed bumblebee again and that seems to have restored things to the way they were. But is that wrong for 14.04?

Comment: No, that is not wrong.