# Installing nVidia driver on hybrid card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, bumblebee

I am running Ubunutu 14.04 and I have just installed it onto my new laptop (MSI PE70 2QE) and it has a hybrid intel/nVidia 960m GFX card.

I have found the excellent post here

[How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

I followed the posts advice by installing Bumblebee then a full shutdown.

Then after startup I installed the driver suggested (319) and rebooted.

I got the nVidea Xorg server window without any profiles or any information.

I have rolled back to a previous disc image and want to try again but wanted to make sure I have read the post correctly by asking what did I possibly did wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to install drivers for this new card is to run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

You will get an option to switch adapters (PRIME) in Nvidia X Server Settings.