Ubuntu freezes during boot when using Linux kernel >= 6.5.0
Update 2024-10-15: I tried different kernels using https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds, and I can confirm that the problem starts from kernel 6.5.0. Any version above that stops booting at either Loading initial ramdisk or EFI stub: Measured initrd data into PCR 9. Using kernel 6.4.0 and below, there is no issue and Ubuntu is booted successfully, except some messages that may be helpful to find out why kernels above 6.5.0 does not work:
[    0.076374] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x0000000078800000-0x000000007affffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes`
[    0.103670] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[    0.391923] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    0.391937] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80

I hope a maintainer see this post and fix it, because I cannot afford a new laptop.
Update 2024-10-14: Using Ventoy I could easily install Kubuntu 24.04.1 on my laptop. But after install I got stuck in the grub menu with the same errors described below. Then I found out adding dis_ucode_ldr to the grub's linux command as described here, solves the problem. The strange part is that Ventoy successfully boots Ubuntu from USB without any issue and without disabling the microcode (Tested as described here in the section: "Checking the microcode version of your CPU"). So I reckon the problem is not related to the microcode but related to grub.
I created a bootable USB flash drive using Startup Disk Creator. During system boot, there were two choices to boot from it: SanDisk 'Cruzer Fit and UEFI: SanDisk 'Cruzer Fit, Partition 2. Kubuntu 22.04 was already installed in UEFI mode, so I chose the second one. Before seeing the GRUB options, two errors were printed (the first rror is not a typo, it was printed without e!)
rror: file '/boot/' not found.
error: can't find command 'grub_platform'.

Then in the GRUB menu, choosing either Try or Install Ubuntu or Ubuntu (safe graphics) result in a black screen. After searching for hours I found out acpi was the culprit. So I tried disabling it by pressing c in the GRUB menu and then entering:
linux (hd0)/casper/vmlinuz root=(hd0) acpi=off
initrd (hd0)/casper/initrd
boot

The above commands without acpi=off prints:
EFI stub: Loaded initrd from LINUX_EFI_INITRD_MEDIA_GUID device path
EFI stub: Measured initrd data into PCR 9

and then nothing happens. But with acpi=off Ubuntu is booted from the USB flash drive, sadly, with 800x600 resolution. Anyway, I could easily install Ubuntu and after installation and rebooting the system I faced the same errors when booting from the SSD in which the Ubuntu was installed on. Now I gave up and switching back to 22.04 :-(, wait I can't! because I removed my 22.04.3 iso file and now I can't download it again because all 22.04 releases point to 24.04.4 which itself causes another error:
[...] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMMR [...], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
[...] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.

Tested with: Ubuntu 24.04, Kubuntu 24.04, Kubuntu 22.04.4 and KDE neon neon-user-20240502-0718 iso files.
System info:
ASUS N552VW,
Latest BIOS release date: 2019/05/29,
Processor: i7-6700HQ,
Memory: 11.6 GiB of RAM,
Graphics: NVIDIA 960m
References:
GNU GRUB Manual 2.12

Black screen is most often the nVidia issue. You need Safe boot on live installer and choose to install optional restricted extras. Is UEFI updated to latest firmware version? I do not have nVidia and do not know for sure if Safe boot is now the option. Sometimes a different installer, different flash drive or different port make a difference. This shows Ubuntu, but Kubuntu now uses the Calamares installer which I like better. Essential the same questions. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

The Nvidia 960m is old enough to have trouble with the newer compilers (gcc-12 on 22.04 point releases 6.5 kernel or gcc-13 24.04 kernel 6.8). Try kernel option "nomodeset" on boot, and check the forums/installation/MaFoelffen for workarounds (manually switching gcc links) to use an older compiler.

See if this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1182214 helps … I remember installing Ubuntu on one of those a couple years ago and I had satisfactory results with the HWE kernel at that time … The problem with those laptops IIRC was the onboard controller/switcher technology (optimus I think) which is developed solely for the Windows OS and that results in issues identifying the video cards combo (one Intel and another nVidia) and even downloading and trying to install proprietary nVidia drivers didn’t work at that time and only HWE kernel gave workable support.

@Raffa Already tested.

Have you tried using etcher or Rufus?

@Rishon_JR Yes.

I apologize for my ignorance, what is the problem with Ubuntu 22.04? What does it mean that the releases point to 24?

Old releases for Ubuntu 22.04 can be downloaded from here: https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jammy/

If you suspect that the issue is caused by your video drivers, you can try installing the correct one. Please refer to this question for more information: https://askubuntu.com/a/474222/1698042

@TalaatEtman The problem is I cannot get past the installation setup and I cannot install the drivers before installing the OS.

Choose the boot partition to boot from.
